# Showing remaining review count while reviewing

Tags: feature-request, review

I think when a user is reviewing it would be useful if they can view their remaining review count in review-bar, such as `14 of 20`.

Can this be implemented?

Comment: State meaning how many reviews left for today?

Comment: It's a good idea, but unfortunately it's already been proposed. You can vote up the other question, and any answers you agree with. Also, if you are passionate about this, feel free to place a bounty on the other question :)

Comment: @James I did it before ;).

Comment: It was only asked a month ago. Given it's only a small request, and nothing is broken, and Stack will be really busy on many other things, even if Stack were to implement it imagine it will take a little while :)